# colorpicker appear behind my ajax control toolkit modal popup

Tags: colors, popup, ajaxcontroltoolkit, picker, behind

My modal css settings are:

```
.ModalWindow {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1000px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

I haver a textbox in y modal popup and the color picker sits next to it. but when I click the colorpicker it goes behind the modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

Add following css style rule: `.ajax__colorPicker_container { z-index: 1001 !important; }` or change `z-index` property of `.ModalWindow` class to 999;